# in redux-form: how to retrieve values still not submitted

Tags: react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a redux-form component which gets initialValues from the redux store in the first load and populates the form. The form is still not submitted. (it was submitted previously but we are in new state from scratch after a user browser reload). The initial Values are populated properly.

```
let CheckoutStep1Form = (props) => {
   return(
     //my fancy form
   )
}

CheckoutStep1Form = reduxForm({
    form: 'step1', // a unique name for this form
})(CheckoutStep1Form);

CheckoutStep1Form = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: {
          //my initial values
        }
    })
)(CheckoutStep1Form)
```

Besides this I have another component which is aiming to summarise  all the form information provided in previous steps in a plain view.

```
const CheckoutStep1Summary = ({values}) => {
   return(
     //my fancy summarize view
   )
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        values: getFormValues('step1')(state)
    })
)(CheckoutStep1Summary)
```

Problem: `getFormValues('step1')(state)` returns empty. No values in the form due not submitted.

So the question is: Can I get the form Values from a form that it was not already submitted in some way using redux-form?

Of course I could do some workaround as I have the values in the state but I would like to know if redux-form is taking in consideration this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, are the values in the form or not? You say "The initial Values are populated properly", which leads me to think yes, but `getFormValues()` isn't doing anything more than returning the values from Redux. I'd recommend using [Redux Dev Tools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) to suss out just what the form state looks like.

You might have just typed it wrong in this question, but this:

```
CheckoutStep1Form = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: {
          //my initial values
        }
    })
)
```

should be this:

```
CheckoutStep1Form = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: {
          //my initial values
        }
    })
)(CheckoutStep1Form) // <-------
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Erik R! The values are passed to the form through initialValues but not submitted, therefore `getFormValues('myForm')(state)` returns undefined in another component. So my assumption was that getFormValues only returns something once the form is submitted.. Am I right? About your hint as you guessed i typed wrong. :) but thanks for pointing out

Comment: No. The `getFormValues()` selector returns the current form values at all times.

Comment: Ok, I was doing a wrong assumption. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @VicensFayos did you get `getFormValues('myForm')(state)` to work? I have a similar scenario (a preview/summery component) and I'm getting the same error.