# Redux- form : get and show all values of a wizard form before submit

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux-form

I'm a beginner, so I'm having some trouble with accessing and showing all values from a Wizard form before submitting the form. I'm trying to create a "preview component" that lets user check all values before s/he hits submit. This is my WIzardFormPreview component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import { Values } from 'redux-form-website-template';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import validate from '../middleware/validate';

let WizardFormPreview = props => {

const {handleSubmit, pristine, previousPage, submitting} = props;

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
        <div className="step-3">

            <div>{familyFlag}</div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" className="previous" onClick={previousPage}>
                    Previous
                </button>
                <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  );
};
export default reduxForm({
form: 'wizard', 
destroyOnUnmount: false, 
forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, 
validate,
})(WizardFormPreview);

WizardFormPreview = connect(
state => ({
    values: {
        family : state.form.wizard.values.familyFlag
    }
})
)(WizardFormPreview)
```

I'm getting "familyFlag is not defined" (which isn't supposed to be, as I understand) but I can't figure out how to make that available. FYI, the input `familyFlag` exists in the first step of the form.

How do I get all values from the wizard form and display it? Helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redux-form` has a selector `getFormValues` that return an object which contains the entire forms' values. The problem was, according to [this bug report](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1658), `values` is a reserved name. It worked as soon as I changed the name. But later on, it worked with the reserved word `values` too. Whether it's a bug or not - is still not certain. I'm posting my full code below (it uses `values`), it may help someone.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm, values, getFormValues } from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import validate from '../middleware/validate';

const FetchValues = connect(state => ({
values: getFormValues('wizard')(state),
}))(({ values }) =>

<div>
    <p>Check if everything is alright.</p>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12">
                <h6>Your Name</h6>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-12">
                <p>{values.name}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12">
            <h6>Are you part of a family?</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-12">
            <p>{values.familyFlag}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>)


let WizardFormPreview = (props) => {

const {handleSubmit, pristine, previousPage, submitting} = props;

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
        <div className="step-3">

            <FetchValues/>
            <div>
                <button type="button" className="previous" onClick={previousPage}>
                    Previous
                </button>
                <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
);
};

export default reduxForm({
form: 'wizard', 
destroyOnUnmount: false,
forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, 
validate,
})(WizardFormPreview);
```

Thanks to @danielrob on github, who provided a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `familyFlag` in the `WizardFormPreview` component

You need to get it from props like

```
let WizardFormPreview = props => {

const {handleSubmit, pristine, previousPage, values, submitting} = props;
const {family: familyFlag} = values;

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
        <div className="step-3">

            <div>{familyFlag}</div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" className="previous" onClick={previousPage}>
                    Previous
                </button>
                <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you. Now the form renders, but I can't see the value for `familyFlag`. It shows undefined instead.

Comment: check if `state.form.wizard.values.familyFlag` is defined in mapStateToProps

Comment: `redux-form` has a `getFormValues` object, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294024/in-redux-form-how-to-retrieve-values-still-not-submitted), it requires ({values}) in the component. can you please help me with some syntax? How to pass both props and values? I think I need props too, to submit the form properly.  I apologize for this super dumb question.

Comment: I have probably found the problem. apparently `values` is a reserved name. This [github issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1658) helped me. I'll update with the full result as soon as I manage to get it done. Thanks a lot again.